# How to draw multiple horizontal lines (Notebook Paper effect) using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a notebook paper on my blog, and i wanted to make horizontal lines in it. I was successfully  able to draw one horizontal line using css, but i am unable to find a way to repeat it, so that it can fill the entire page.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.horizontalLines {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 padding-top: 25px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

This code only allows me to make only one line, how can i make multiple lines?

Comment: Can you show the HTML you applied this to? That would help us understand how you want to achieve this...

Comment: Your HTML help us to answer.

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#lined-paper

Comment: For multiple horizontal lines it would be better if you consider to add them dynamically using Javascript **or** just use a background image and repeat it using background-repeat property.

Comment: sounds like a repeating background image would be the best solution as drawing the horizontal lines using on elements sounds like a nightmare!! how are you going to deal with images etc.

Answer (score 16):

As an alternate solution, there's a beautiful lined paper effect written using CSS available [here](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#lined-paper).

```
background-color: #fff; 
background-image: 
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 79px, #abced4 79px, #abced4 81px, transparent 81px),
linear-gradient(#eee .1em, transparent .1em);
background-size: 100% 1.2em;
```

> **[Browser Support](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#browser-support)**: The patterns themselves should work on Firefox 3.6+, Chrome, Safari 5.1, Opera 11.10+ and IE10+. However, implementation limitations might cause some of them to not be
>   displayed correctly even on those browsers (for example at the time of
>   writing, Gecko is quite buggy with radial gradients).

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I combined this with flex-grow to make dynamic lined paper at the bottom of reports for people to write comments.

Answer (score 3):

Using your way you have to insert multiple of these elements. You can't simply repeat them.

Another - and I guess more suitable way - would be using a background image that you repeat horizontally and vertically to achieve this effect.

```
body {
    background: transparent url(path/filename) repeat 0 0;
}
```

Or, if you can use gradients, [nikhita dkslfslg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183509/1456376) (+1 for that) might help.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
.paper {
background-image:url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFgAsAJEAAP////n8/ePv9gAAACH5BAAHAP8ALAAAAAAWACwAAAInhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrZuFsTyTNeBgOf6zgsFADs=");
```

}

Just Encode an image in base64 and it works fine.

You can try encoding  [HERE](https://www.base64-image.de/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with box shadows:

```
.lines{
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px 0px black, 0px 20px 0px 0px green, 0px 30px 0px 0px blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7DkKc/

Or simply with images:

```
.lines{
    background: transparent url(url) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

Or with gradients.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Can't be done using `box-shadow`. you know that. :) (There are many lines, not just three).

Comment: Yes, but it is  a part of solution. The best way will be my second answer. Repeating gradients. They are in SVG generated. Good for HD and Retina displays.